# How do I save a specific "state" of the product in the order item?

Tags: commerce, 9

I'd be necessary for my site to save "a specific state" of the product(s) and relative variation(s) purchased in the order.

I mean, with the "standard" Commerce configuration, in the relative [order item](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/order-items) are stored only:

> a reference to the purchasable entity, a quantity, a unit price and a total price

Therefore, for example if the *body* of the purchased product or relative variation is changed after a user buy it, it is impossible to get and show the value of it at the moment of the purchase.

Is there a module\way to preserve that information in the order item?

I'm thinking at worst to somehow programmatically save that at the moment of the order item creation, but before proceeding I'd like to check existing solutions etc but unfortunately I've found nothing about.

I am using the Commerce module 2.x.

Comment: I think the proper way would be to have product revisions, and then relate the order item to that revision,  but that may only ever be in the form of a patch ex: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2656896.

I would probably either opt to 1) never edit, only create new products  or 2) store a JSON output of the product data in an order item field.

Comment: I'd avoid to put a so critical patch. Good idea with the json field. Is there a service to save an entity (namely commerce product, in this case) to JSON? Should I use serialization api?

Comment: Honestly I would probably try to $entity->toArray() and json_encode() after I parsed out the data I actually want,  
-----
but it would be coolers to serialize the entity like:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/serialization-api-overview
-----
\Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface
-----
$output = $this->serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
-----
$entity = $this->serializer->deserialize($output, Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation::class, 'json');